# How to show pop up on image on click and show all images in that pop up

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework, popup

I have one grid view which will show the list of images available in db. Now I need one onClick function that will trigger When ever user press on any image. When clicked on that particular image, same should show as pop up screen and on that pop up screen i need two buttons as both left and right and move to see other images.

Here my code for display the list of images in gridview :

```
<div ng-repeat="eventimgs in MediaURL">

    <div class="row"  ng-if="$even">

        <div class="col col-50"><img ng-src="{{MediaURL[$index]}}" style="width: 100%;height: 217px;object-fit: cover;" /></div>

        <div class="col col-50"><img ng-src="{{MediaURL[$index + 1]}}"style="width: 100%;height: 217px;object-fit: cover;"/></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Now how can I make a on click function that will show pop up on and display the image on which image its clicks? And followed by other images by pressing left and right button in pop up screen.

Comment: use ionic modal - http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicModal/

Comment: i am new to ionic. If u explain what to do it will be help full.. Like i need to design new screen to show the images for full screen .with button on right and left.am i right ??

Comment: use fancybox: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/